# Amount of audio played out of jitter buffer

Tags: audio, voip, jitter

I am looking at a [tutorial](https://www.cs.csustan.edu/~john/Classes/Previous_Semesters/CS3000_Communication_Networks/2018_02_Spring/Notes/chap28.html) on jitter buffer. It has the following diagram:

[image]

My understanding is that in case of adaptive jitter buffer, 'd' may vary over time. My question is that since a system is asking for audio data (in case of VoIP), will the amount the data given to the system by adaptive jitter buffer vary over time ?

Comment: I think the specifics of the system and codec is going to matter.  More importantly... what's the context of your question?

Comment: @Brad Lets say the system is a mobile OS like Android. A VoIP app is using adaptive jitter buffer. I understand that adaptive jitter buffer will adjust the queue size based on delay observed in incoming traffic. My question is that when the Android system asks the app for audio, will the adaptive jitter buffer always provide the same amount of audio (say 500 bytes each time), OR will it adjust how much audio data it provides to the system for playback ?

Comment: @Brad I am trying to ask that is it a requirement for an adaptive jitter buffer to always provide the same amount of audio for each request from the system, OR does "adaptive" imply that in addition to changing queue size for delay, the algorithm may also change how much data it provides the system upon request ?